# Show zero when all rows are filtered out in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, zero

I am building a dashboard in the Tableau. I want to count how many candidates in the group. After applying all filters, I have no candidates and I want to show 0 in the sheet but it can only display nothing. How can I put 0 as an indicator there?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot / example of where this 0 should appear?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're filtering out all the rows in your table and so there are no rows left in order to aggregate.

You may bypass this "problem" switching your filtering logic to parameters and let your calculated field do the rest.

For instance, assuming you have one row for each candidate, you may want to have a CF called Candidates Number like:

```
sum(if    column = parameter
      and column2 = parameter2
      ...
   then 1
   else 0
   end
)
```

It's not a perfect way, but since filters are the equivalent of a where clause, you "lose" all your non-matching rows.

Using parameters, you do not lose rows, but you have to "translate" your logic into calculated field.

Hope it could help.